# Handling Multidimensional Arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've coordinates as groups. All group must be stored as seperated. First I stored them list in list in list like this:

```
PointOne: numpy.array([x, y, z])
GroupOne: numpy.array([PointOne, PointTwo ... PointLast])

All Points : [GroupOne, GroupTwo, GroupThree]
```

I feel that my approach is little wrong and numpy has capability to store all of them as seperated. I could set a column as group number but it is silly.

Throughout, I want to store my coordinates like NetCDF , HDF5 etc. You know there are dimensional ( they call variables ) like propagation, temperature etc. So you can store your values in temperature variable (dimension) as 3D also 4D arrays. But they're seperated, so user can access them like:

```
readed_netcdf.temperate[5,2]
```

How can i do that in numpy world?

By the way I want this to make something as following best methods and in the future I'll use numba to calculate everything with big performance.

numpy version : 1.16.2

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do with the coordinates. Are you trying to store your data in NetCDF?

Comment: @Istwan No I am not trying to store netcdf. I said netcdf because of it's dimensional approach. You can store many values at one coordinate in netcdf. They call variables like i told above. This is what i want to store my coordinates as dimensional in numpy array.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  The `numpy` `ndarray` is multidimensional in pure array sense - it has a `shape` `(n,m,p,...)` (0d upto 32d), and can be indexed as such `[i,j,k...]`.  But indexing is strictly by count, 0,1,2,.... It does not attach a scale to any dimension (like the `lat` or `long` scales of a NetCDF).  You can of course make 1d arrays like that, and use your own code to coordinate the scale arrays and the data arrays.

Comment: In `h5py` terminology you asking about `dimension scales`. 
 http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dims.html.  There scales can be attached to the `dims` property of a `dataset`,  "But A dimension scale is simply another HDF5 dataset."  You could download those scales to your `numpy` session, but maintaining `dims` like links between the data arrays and their scales is your responsibility.  There isn't a `numpy` mechanism to do that for you.

Comment: @hpaulj I am not sure dimension scales is same thing what i told but you got the idea. I want to scale my data to another dimensions. Numpy or pandas has rows and columns. I want to maintain rows and columns and add more data for same **index**. So this is dimension in my problem. And as you told there is no mechanism on numpy. So can you tell me what kind of approach can be followed?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), you can create N-dimensional arrays as follows:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.ndarray(shape = (5,3)) # 5 Rows by 3 columns
```

What follows below is the shape described:

```
[[,,],
 [,,],
 [,,],
 [,*,],
 [,,]]
```

If you want to access the element where I put the aterisk (the '*' character), you would do so as follows:

```
arr[3,1] #Access the 4th row, 2nd column
```

These elements can then be accessed via [indexing or slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing) of the array. In the above case, the 5 rows could be used for as 5 points (each with 3 dimensions). Let me know if this answers your question. I'll be happy to provide more example code if needed.

Comment: In fact it is not multi-dimensional. At least not like netcdf-dimensions. Numpy sees rows as dimensions but it is not what i meant.

Comment: @UmutÜçok Hmm, it _is_ multidimensional, as it has more than one dimension. For the concrete example here: 2. But you can easily adapt this example to more dimensions if you want. It's the same thing like in netcdf: there you would have defined two dimensions, e.g. `Temp` and `Prop`, the one has length 5, the other length 3. Then you define a first variable, e.g. `arr` as a variable which depends on these two dimensions. Voila, a 2D-variable. Exactly what jsonV did here with numpy. You can choose to have more dimensions here and there, in netcdf and in numpy, that's not the difference...

Comment: ...however: the main differences i'm aware of are regarding of _unlimited dimensions_ which are of course a convenient thing in netcdf4, which do not exist in numpy, and _indexing_, which is a bit different. But both seem not to be in the scope of your question (by now...)

Comment: Never used netcdf but the numpy sample code does allow for a multidimensional array. As named, ndarrays are n-dimensional arrays. Also, rows are not strictly dimensions in numpy @UmutÜçok. You can do whatever you want with them but must decide on a representation of your array.

You could easily construct a nested n-dimensional array as it appears you were trying to do initially to achieve this unlimited dimensions SpghttCd speaks of:

(e.g.
arr = np.ndarray((3,3))
nested = np.ndarray((2,2))

arr[1,1] = nested
)

The above is illustrated as:
[[*,*,*],
 [*,[2x2],*],
 [*,*,*]]

Comment: Thanks guys for all answers. So if I conclude the result: dimensions in numpy array means same in netcdf too. I can create multi-dimensional numpy array with different rows. Nested n-dim array I think what i want in the result.